# I am trying to get current date with form select option and display next seven days on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If the current date is 3/11/14 and the user picks Wednesday then 3/12/14, 3/
19/14, 3/26/14, 4/2/14, 4/9/14, 4/16/14 should print.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
                                        <select  id="selectDay" placeholder="Favorite day of the week"> 
                             <option selected="selected" ></option>
                             <option value="1">Monday</option>
                             <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
                             <option value="3">Wednesday</option> 
                             <option value="4">Thursday</option>
                             <option value="5">Friday</option>
                             <option value="6">Saturday</option>
                             <option value="7">Sunday</option>
                            </select>
                                      </div>

JAVASCRIPT
$(document).ready(function(){
    var CurrentDate=new Date();

    $("#selectDay").val(CurrentDate.getDate());
  });
```

Comment: It might help if you use unambiguous dates like "March 11, 2014" or "11 March, 2014". If today is Monday 10 March and the user picks Sunday, is that Sunday 9 or 16 March?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.
http://jsfiddle.net/dfc8e/8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selectDay").change(function () {
        var day = parseInt($("#selectDay").val());
        var CurrentDate = new Date();
        var offset = CurrentDate.getDay() < day ? 0 : 7;
        var addDays = day + offset - CurrentDate.getDay();
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            CurrentDate.setDate(CurrentDate.getDate() + addDays);
            alert(CurrentDate);
            if (i == 0) {
                addDays = 7;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/pbyTA/2/)

with the `date` object, you should have no problem to print what you want by youself

```
function show(){
var list = document.getElementById("selectDay");
var day = parseInt(list.options[list.selectedIndex].value); //you would need to parse it to int if you want to do math

var currentDate = new Date().getDate();
var tick = new Date().setDate(currentDate+day); // this will give you the last date
var d = new Date(tick);

var x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=d;
}
```

You can study on how to use `date` object at [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)